# Query to get yesterday date with specific amount of time

Tags: sql-server, date-math

I am struggling to query for a specific time frame between 21:50 and 21:59:

```
SELECT
 Username,
 EventTime,
 EventsEx.FirstName,
 EventsEx.Surname,
 PeripheralName,
 EventTypeDescription,
 CardNumber
 FROM Net2.sdk.EventsEx
 LEFT JOIN Net2.sdk.UsersEx 
        ON EventsEx.FirstName = UsersEx.FirstName 
       AND EventsEx.Surname = UsersEx.Surname

 WHERE EventTime >= DATEADD(day, -1, convert(date, GETDATE())) 
   AND EventTime < CONVERT(date, GETDATE())
 ORDER BY EventTime
```

`EventTime` example:

```
EventTime
2019-09-05 07:17:05.000
```

I am looking to see if the `EventTime` occurs between those times on yesterday's day.

Comment: Welcome to DBA.SE and thanks for your patriticipation. Could you possibly provide the DDL of the tables in question? Or is the column `EventTime` a `date` data type or possibly `smalldattime`, `datetime` or `datetime2()`? Cold you be a bit more specific? The more information you provide the easier it is for us to assist you.

Comment: thanks @hot2use im trying to provie my best but im beginner with database. Could you please help me how can I get ddl of this tables?

Comment: If you have SQL Server Management Studio installed, then you can right-click any table and then hit `Script table as ...` and then the sub-option `Create in ...` and either of the following options. Otherwise ask your friendly developer or database administrator for a copy of the data definition language of the involved table(s).

Answer (score 1):

The `BETWEEN` [logical operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/between-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) will be perfect for this:

```
SELECT
 Username,
 EventTime,
 EventsEx.FirstName,
 EventsEx.Surname,
 PeripheralName,
 EventTypeDescription,
 CardNumber
 FROM Net2.sdk.EventsEx
 LEFT JOIN Net2.sdk.UsersEx ON EventsEx.FirstName = UsersEx.FirstName AND EventsEx.Surname = UsersEx.Surname
 WHERE EventTime BETWEEN convert(time,'21:50') AND convert(time,'21:59')
    AND convert(date, EventTime) >= DATEADD(day, -1, convert(date, GETDATE())) AND EventTime < CONVERT(date, GETDATE())
 ORDER BY EventTime
```

This will look for times between the times specified in the first condition after the `WHERE` statement.

`BETWEEN` is inclusive and will also check for times at the boundary values specified. 21:50 and 21:59 will meet the condition in the example.

Your check is still present to limit the conditions to only look at the previous day

Comment: Thanks for your help. I received error message:
The data types datetime and time are incompatible in the greater than or equal to operator.

Comment: Try it now. The `EventTime` is now a date when being compared.